# How do I position button to the bottom right using css

Tags: css

When I tried to position the button to the bottom left, it worked but when I go to one of the buttons and go back it has all of the buttons there but one? the other one I need to scroll down to see please help

**HTML**

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
  <title>Forsaken </title>
  <link href="main.css" rel="stlesheet" type="text/css">
  </head>

   <body>


  <a href="teams.html"><button><img class="#topleft" src="icon1.jpg  " width="100%" alt="Teams" ></button></a>
  <a href="store.html"><button><img class="#topright" src="icon2.jpg  " width="100%" alt="store" ></button></a>
  <a href="sponsors.html"><button><img class="#bottomleft" src="icon4.jpg  " width="100%" alt="sponsors" ></button></a>
  <a href="aboutus.html"><button><img class="#bottomright" src="icon3.jpg  " width="100%" alt="aboutus" ></button></a>


</body>


</html>
```

**CSS**

```
#topleft {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px; 
    left: 0px;
}

#topright {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
}

#left {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
}

#right {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0px;
}


div {
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:0px;   
    border-color:#000000;
}

#yes {
  border: none;
    padding: 0;
    background: none;
}

.flat {
    border: none;
    background: #222;
    color: #FFF;
    padding: 0px 0px;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-family: Palatino;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.lighter {
    background: #666;
}

#no {
  border: none;
    padding: 0;
    background: none;
}

.flat {
    border: none;
    background: #222;
    color: #FFF;
    padding: 0px 0px;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-family: Palatino;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.lighter {
    background: #666;
}
```

**p.s** All the other buttons are working but the About Us one.

Comment: add your html code also.

Comment: You didn't specify the particular class/id you need help with because your html code isn't available

Answer (score 1):

### Try this:

```css
.topLeft{
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
}
.topRight{
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  right: 0;
}
.bottomLeft{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.bottomRight{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right:0;
}
```

```html
<button class="topLeft"><a href="#">Click Me</a></button>
<button class="topRight"><a href="#">Click Me</a></button>
<button class="bottomLeft"><a href="#">Click Me</a></button>
<button class="bottomRight"><a href="#">Click Me</a></button>
```

[Working Codepen](http://codepen.io/liorgrs/pen/EKjawJ)

#### Note

Do not use hashtags inside a class declaretion, it's bad practice (hashtags used to catch id's).

That's why your code did not worked.

Reply if there are any issues..

Comment: will it work if I add all the images back? if so where do I put the code? and before I put the images in the (Click me) little buttons aren't in all corners