# CSS how to position a image bottom right

Tags: html, css

When I tried to position the button to the bottom left, it worked but when I go to one of the buttons and go back it has all of the buttons there but one? the other one I need to scroll down to see please help

**HTML**

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
  <title>Forsaken </title>
  <link href="main.css" rel="stlesheet" type="text/css">
  </head>

   <body>


  <a href="teams.html"><button><img class="#topleft" src="icon1.jpg  " width="100%" alt="Teams" ></button></a>
  <a href="store.html"><button><img class="#topright" src="icon2.jpg  " width="100%" alt="store" ></button></a>
  <a href="sponsors.html"><button><img class="#bottomleft" src="icon4.jpg  " width="100%" alt="sponsors" ></button></a>
  <a href="aboutus.html"><button><img class="#bottomright" src="icon3.jpg  " width="100%" alt="aboutus" ></button></a>


</body>


</html>
```

**CSS**

```
#topleft {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px; 
    left: 0px;
}

#topright {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
}

#left {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
}

#right {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0px;
}


div {
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:0px;   
    border-color:#000000;
}

#yes {
  border: none;
    padding: 0;
    background: none;
}

.flat {
    border: none;
    background: #222;
    color: #FFF;
    padding: 0px 0px;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-family: Palatino;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.lighter {
    background: #666;
}

#no {
  border: none;
    padding: 0;
    background: none;
}

.flat {
    border: none;
    background: #222;
    color: #FFF;
    padding: 0px 0px;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-family: Palatino;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.lighter {
    background: #666;
}
```

**p.s** All the other buttons are working but the About Us one.

Comment: You don't have any CSS for #bottomright and #bottomleft? Your code is also trying to do weird things, so I'd suggest looking up some tutorials.

Comment: Why you use buttons inside `<a>` tag

Comment: Where is the `#bottomright` and `#bottomleft` css

Comment: Also with the class, don't add the #.
The # tells the style that you are targeting an id. 
The . tells the style that you are targeting a class.
Just name them bottomleft, bottomright, topleft, topright.

Comment: Please do not use hash symbols in class names, it confuses them with `id`s.

Comment: everyone i putted in new code but it still doesn't work i will post paste-bins links below thank you

Comment: html http://pastebin.com/kCNxS13J css http://pastebin.com/q9fqYsWi thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

change your code from:

```
#left {
position: fixed;
left: 0px;
}

#right {
position: fixed;
right: 0px;
}
```

to

```
.bottomleft{
position: fixed;
left: 0px;
}

.bottomright{
position: fixed;
right: 0px;
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: html http://pastebin.com/nkhVjsRY css http://pastebin.com/q9fqYsWi i have new code please check it out and they both still don't work thanks for your help

Comment: @CreepyC take a screen shot of your page, and paste it somewhere so I can get an idea of the current situation.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35740350/how-do-i-position-button-to-the-bottom-right-using-css/35741410?noredirect=1#comment59203116_35741410